# SQL split column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made an easy exemple to understand better what is my question. 
So, i have 2 table and i have a selection based on `inner join` which is into a selection.

```
create table students(
id_student number,
name_student varchar2(15),
id_advisor number,
money number
);

insert into students values(1, 'Student_1', 1, 100);
insert into students values(2, 'Student_2', 8,-200);
insert into students values(4, 'Student_4', 7, 256);
insert into students values(5, 'Student_5', 3, -305);   
----------------

create table advisors(
id_advisor number,
name_advisor varchar2(15)
);

insert into advisors values(1, 'advisor_1');
insert into advisors values(3, 'advisor_3'); 
insert into advisors values(5, 'advisor_5');

------------------------------------------
SELECT name_advisor, money as money_pozitive
FROM(
select name_student, name_advisor, money from students 
inner join advisors on students.id_advisor = advisors.id_advisor)
WHERE money > 0
```

With this code i have the following result:

```
name_advisor    |    money_pozitive
------------------------------------
advisor_1       |    100
```

My question is, how I add an extra column named `money_negative`  with of course  negative values ? like this:

```
name_advisor    |    money_pozitive    |  money_negative
---------------------------------------------------------
advisor_1       |    100               |  -305
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `case`:

```
select name_student, name_advisor,
       (case when money > 0 then money end) as money_positive,
       (case when money < 0 then money end) as money_negative
from students s inner join
     advisors a
     on s.id_advisor = a.id_advisor;
```

Notes:

- A subquery is not necessary.
- Use table aliases.  These make a query easier to write and to read.
- If you have multiple table names, it is a good habit to qualify all column names (i.e., use the table aliases for the column names).
- And you don't need a `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me how can i remove null values? from this 2 columns?

Comment: @Marius . . . Use `else 0` in the `case` if you want zero instead of `NULL`.